# Determining if a vector belongs to a convex set by using support function

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Take a convex set $A$ that is a subset of the $(n-1)$-dimensional simplex. In particular, $\forall a\equiv (a_1,...,a_n) \in A$, $a_i\in [0,1]$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i=1$.

Quoting from a book: it follows that 
$$
(\diamond) \hspace{1cm} a^*\in A\Leftrightarrow b'a^*-\underbrace{\sup_{a\in A} b'a}_{\text{support function}} \leq 0 \text{ }\forall b \in \mathcal{B}
$$
where $\mathcal{B}\equiv \{b\in \mathbb{R}^n: b'b\leq 1\}$.

**Question 1:** Why are we checking $b'a^*-\sup_{a\in A} b'a \leq 0$ only for the $b$s in the unit ball? Is this related with the fact that $A$ is a subset of the $(n-1)$-dimensional simplex?

**Question 2:** Is $(\diamond)$ equivalent to 
$$
(\diamond \diamond) \hspace{1cm} a^*\in A\Leftrightarrow b'a^*-\sup_{a\in A} b'a \leq 0 \text{ }\forall b \in \mathcal{S}
$$
where $\mathcal{S}\equiv \{b\in \mathbb{R}^n: b'b= 1\}$? That is, is it sufficient to check the $b$s in the unit sphere?

Comment: Your notation is all mixed up. The supremum cannot be over $b\in A$, as it does not depend on $b$.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake!!! Fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both questions in effect ask the same, so one answer suffices.

**Answers $1\& 2$.**

(should be : "only for $b'$s in the unit ball, not $b$s). This because the support function is homogeneous, so that in the inequality
$$b'a*\leq\sup_{a\in A}b'a$$
we can multiply both sides by any positive number without changing the inequality. In particular, we can divide by the norm of $b'$, thus obtaining a unit vector.
This is not related to the specific structure of the set $A$.